# Is this PHP class optimized for mysql database access?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, class

I've wrote a quick PHP class to ease the access to a mysql database. The class works ok, and has a query() method that opens up the connection, executes the query and then closes the connection (I know that the connection is supposed to close by PHP itself after the script finishes, but I don't like to rely very much on that).

From a performance standpoint, I know that always opening a connection to a database every time I execute a query may not be a very good practice (and also that when I try to use mysql_real_escape_string() to filter input, it doesn't work, because there's no active database connection). But I would like to be more clarified about this. Is it very wrong to do? Why? And I would also like to know about good alternatives to this.

Here's the class:

```
class DB {

private $conn;

//database data
private $dbhost;
private $dbname;
private $dbuser;
private $dbpass;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @dbhost string the database host
 * @dbname string the database name
 * @dbuser string the database username
 * @dbpass string the database password
 */
public function __construct ($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass)
{
    $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
    $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = $dbpass;
}

/**
 * Connects to mysql database
 */
private function open ()
{
    $this->conn = mysql_connect ($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass)
    or die ("Error connecting to database");

    mysql_select_db ($this->dbname) or die ("Error selecting database");
}

/**
 * Closes the connection to a database
 */
private function close ()
{
    mysql_close($this->conn);
}

/**
 * Executes a given query string
 * @param string $query the query to execute
 * @return mixed the result object on success, False otherwise
 */
public function query ($query)
{   
    $this->open();
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->conn)
    or die ("Error executing query ".$query." ".mysql_error());

    $this->close();
    return $result;

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you even need this class in the first place? It doesn't seem to be adding anything to the standard functions. And if anything, you should be using PDO or mysqli, not mysql_* functions.

Comment: And also: "Is it very wrong to do?" If that's in reference to you not using mysql_real_escape_string(), yes, it's very very very wrong. But again, mysqli or PDO parameterized queries would be a much better solution.

Comment: No, it was not about using mysql_real_escape_string(), that's essential. It was about opening the connection every time I query the DB. The class itself doesn't add anything functional, but its a layer of abstraction to the database, instead of polluting the code with repeated function calls and error handling.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> (I know that the connection is supposed to close by PHP itself after the script finishes, but I don't like to rely very much on that).

Why? This is a feature of the language. There's no reason to not trust it. A lot of websites are running just fine counting on PHP to close their stuff. As programmers, of course, we want to close it ourselves. That's fine. But opening and closing a database connection for every query is a *horrible* idea. The better way to do it is to call `open()` from your constructor, and rename your `close()` to [`__destruct()`](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.decon). According to the documentation, `__destruct` will be called "as soon as all references to a particular object are removed or when the object is explicitly destroyed or in any order in shutdown sequence."  Sounds like an ideal place to stash away the closing code for your database connection.

Comment: To further elaborate, opening a database connection is a pretty expensive operation.  With some DBMSs, opening a connection can take more resources than querying, for simple queries.

Also, you completely break anything that lives for the duration of a connection, like transactions, temporary tables, per-connection variables, etc.

Reconnecting between every query is really, really ugly, and there's no good reason to do it.

Comment: It should be noted that the __destruct() method only works in PHP5+. In PHP4 the code will still run, but __destruct will not be called automatically. The database will still be closed at the end of the script of course.